# Ubuntu 14.04 on HP S7620.uk with Nvidia GeForce 7500 LE

Tags: drivers, 14.04, nvidia

Hi I am looking to setup a dual boot on a HP S7620.uk with Win XP and Ubuntu 14.04

When I tried running Ubuntu 14.04 from a DVD without installing I got several lines of errors saying the GPU had timed out, eventually it offered to run in low graphics mode.

Will it be a case of install Ubuntu and then update the graphics drivers or will it be a lot more involved?

This is my first go at using Ubuntu!

Thanks.